# Android ICS Network Location not updating

Tags: android, networking, location, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application that I used to test in my Android phone with 2.3.3 and it uses GPS and Network Location. However, I tried in two different ICS (4.0+) phones and the network location never updates. I have the required permissions in the manifest (INTERNET, ACCESS_LOCATION, ACCESS_GPS, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) and it used to work.

I'm able to get a location "hint" in ICS through lastKnownLocation, but I really need network location enabled. It still works on the Android 2.3.3 but not on more recent versions.

Is there anything I must change for ICS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem on my both 4.1.1 Android phones. It seems that location somehow "stuck" to one location and doesn't want to change.

Restart phone and location updates will start to work OK.

I also tried other applications from the Play Market that use MapView, and they also couldn't find my current location. GoogleMaps application was not influenced with this problem, and it always worked OK.

BTW, you are using more permissions than you need. You must include android.permission.INTERNET, and one of the following: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! I had restarted the phone before since it ran out of battery, but the GPS seems to be reset only if you actually choose the "reboot" option! Thanks so much!

Regarding the permissions, I was rather desperate... So I just threw everything I could to try to solve the problem. :) Thanks again!

Comment: this is not a solution for my users, I have seen this on Galaxy S3 and Nexus 4 , have you encountered a better solution since then?

Answer (score 2):

After device reboot the network location provider works fine but after some time it stops updating.

This is known issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707

Unfortunately without solution yet. So please vote for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar problem with huawei G330D (4.0.4)- network location does not work at all (even the initial lastKnownLocation return null), despite the fact that google apps (Maps, Local) work OK and display network location correctly.
Still could not find how to solve it :-(

Comment: This should've been a comment